# Message of Throwable shows wrong text

Tags: java, exception

I am working on some legacy code which has a very ugly and dirty hack to handle some exceptions we're getting from a 3rd party service, but at least we have a test for it. For some reason the hack isn't working in the branch I am working on.

We're mocking the service and we're throwing the exception that we sometimes get from the service:

```
throw new EJBTransactionRolledbackException("SystemException: Entity not found: 'Item with id " + someId + "'. resultTextDetails: [] constraintViolations: []");
```

Our hack simply checks for the message of the exception and does some things afterwards. Really ugly, but it worked:

```
public void exceptionHandling(final Throwable t){
    if (t.getMessage().contains(PART_OF_EXCEPTION_TEXT)){
        // some logic here
    }
}
```

For some reason t.getMessage() doesn't show the message we're throwing but  the message of the "caused by" part of the stacktrace:

> Caused by:
>   com...ServiceProxiesNotWorkingException:
>   **Relookup of service proxies failed!**

My questions:

- Why does t.getMessage() show the "caused by" part and not the the text of the exception itself?
- Is there a way to always get the text of the exception itself?

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: caused by shows from where exception has been raised.

Comment: @almasshaikh - But the code that throws the exception didn't change. hmmm... maybe the place where we call that code changed. That could be an idea.

Comment: The message depends on the implementation. If you're not chaining an exception you might want to make sure you're catching precisely the same exception you're throwing-the code path may not be what you think it is.

Comment: `Throwable t;
         while (true) {
          t = e.getCause();
          if (t == null) {
           break;
          }
          System.out.println(t.getMessage());
         }`Try this within your catch block.

Comment: Can you create custom exception classes that extend from the EJB exception you have there, and catch them instead? Or use a catch(Throwable) like you have, but use instanceof to find the right exception?

Comment: @almasshaikh: I am giving that a try, thank you.